# Convergence of sequences of inverse functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(X, \phi)$ and $(Y, \sigma)$ be metric spaces, and let

1. $f, f_1, f_2, \ldots$ bijective function with inverse functions $g, g_1, g_2, \ldots$
2. $f_n \to f$ pointwise for $n \to \infty$.

And all involved functions are continuous. Does it hold that $g_n \to g$ pointwise for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: See also: https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107422/ArchMath_027-1991-2_9.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

If $y=f(x)$ and $y_n=f_n(x)$ then
$$
|g(y)-g_n(y)|=|x-g_n(\;y-y_n+y_n\;)|=|g_n(y_n)-g_n(y_n + e_n)|
$$
where $e_n=y-y_n \rightarrow 0$.

Therefore **if** $\{g_n\}$ **is uniformly equicontinuous** the answer is yes:
$$
|g(y)-g_n(y)|\le \sigma(e_n)
$$
where $\sigma$ is the modulus of continuity of the family $\{g_n\}$.