# Linear convergence of sequences of inverse functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, limits, inverse-function

Let $f, f_n: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f^{-1}, f_n^{-1}$ exist and are globally Lipschitz continuous for all $n$ (same constant $L$).

Assume that $f_n := f + \frac{1}{n} Id$. Then $\left( f_n \right)^{-1} \rightarrow f^{-1}$ uniformly on every compact set.

Prove or disprove that $\left\| \left( f_n \right)^{-1} - \left( f \right)^{-1}\right\| \leq \frac{c}{n}$, for some $c>0$.

Comments: $\left( f_n \right)^{-1} \rightarrow f^{-1}$ follows from the Lipschitz continuity property, see: [Convergence of sequences of inverse functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483428/convergence-of-sequences-of-inverse-functions). However, that does not exploit the fact that $\left( f_n \right)^{-1} = \left( f + \frac{1}{n} Id \right)^{-1}$.

Attempt: If we take $x = \left( f + \frac{1}{n}Id \right) (y) = f(y) + \frac{1}{n} y$, then 
$\left\| \left( f + \frac{1}{n}Id \right)^{-1}(x) - f^{-1}(x)  \right\| = 
\left\| y - f^{-1}\left( f(y) + \frac{1}{n} y \right)  \right\| = 
\left\| f^{-1}\left( f(y) \right) - f^{-1}\left( f(y) + \frac{1}{n} y \right)  \right\| \leq L \left\| f(y)  - f(y) + \frac{1}{n} y \right\| = L \left\|  \frac{1}{n} y \right\| = \frac{L}{n} \left\| y \right\|$.

So the statement holds if $\left\| y \right\|$ is bounded, i.e. if the domain of $f$ is bounded. Otherwise it seems the statement may be false.

Comment: hint: $f_n^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(y - \frac1n)$.

Comment: Why is that? $f_n^{-1}(y) = \left( f + \frac{1}{n} Id\right)^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: you changed $f_n$ from $f+\frac1n$ to $f+\frac1n\operatorname{id}$. If $f$ is decreasing, then $f+\frac1n\operatorname{id}$ need not be invertible for every $n$ (just for large $n$).

Comment: I see. I meant $f + \frac{1}{n} Id$. I implicitly assume that $f + \frac{1}{n} Id = f_n$ is invertible. And its inverse is in fact $f_n^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f_n$ is bijective for sufficiently large $n$.

Big hint:
$$ \| f_n^{-1} - f^{-1} \| = \| \operatorname{id}  - f^{-1} \circ f_n \| = \| f^{-1}\circ f  - f^{-1} \circ f_n \|. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried a similar attempt, see the question. So do I need the domain of $f$ to be bounded?

Comment: @user284439: oh wait, your $f_n$ does not converges to $f$ uniformly!

Comment: Right! But if the domains of $f$ and $f_n$ are bounded, then it would all work...

Comment: @user284439: na $f$ and $f_n$ have different image. It would be difficult to define $f_n^{-1} - f^{-1}$. Better just say that $f_n^{-1}$ converges  uniformly to $f^{-1}$ on every compact subset.

Comment: I am now not sure about the step $\left\| f_n^{-1} - f^{-1} \right\| = \left\| \text{id} - f^{-1} \circ f_n \right\|$. I would instead write that $\left\| f_n^{-1} - f^{-1} \right\| = \left\| \left( \text{id} - f^{-1} \circ f_n \right) \circ f_n^{-1} \right\|$

Comment: @user284439 Well $f_n$ is bijective. That won't change anything. If you go for local uniform convergence you need to track the domain/set more carefully.